# Cannot find module '../Button.module.scss' from 'src/widgets/Button/ui/Button.tsx'

Tags: reactjs

After running `npm run unit Button.test.ts` in the console, I encountered the following error:

```bash
Test suite failed to run
Cannot find module '../Button.module.scss' from 'src/widgets/Button/ui/Button.tsx'  
Require stack:
src/widgets/Button/ui/Button.tsx  
src/widgets/Button/ui/Button.test.tsx
```

I tried adding "modulePaths" to Jest.config.ts, but it did not help me. Maybe someone knows why I am encountering this problem and what I need to do to fix it?
If you need more information I can show you.

The files being used are shown below:

```json
//tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "allowJs": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["./src/*"]
    },
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "ts-node": {
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "CommonJS",
      "esm": true
    }
  },
  "include": ["./config/jest/setupTest.ts"]
}


// global.d.ts
declare module '*.scss' {
  interface IClassNames {
    [className: string]: string;
  }
  const classNames: IClassNames;
  export = classNames;
}

declare module '*.png';
declare module '*.jpg';
declare module '*.jpeg';
declare module '*.svg' {
  import React from 'react';

  const SVG: React.VFC<React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>>;
  export default SVG;
}

declare const __IS__DEV__: boolean;


// Jest.config.ts
export default {
  preset: 'ts-jest/presets/default-esm', // or other ESM presets
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^(\\.{1,2}/.*)\\.js$': '$1'
  },
  transform: {
    // '^.+\\.[tj]sx?$' to process js/ts with `ts-jest`
    // '^.+\\.m?[tj]sx?$' to process js/ts/mjs/mts with `ts-jest`
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': [
      'ts-jest',
      {
        useESM: true
      }
    ]
  },
  clearMocks: true,
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  coveragePathIgnorePatterns: ['\\\\node_modules\\\\'],
  moduleFileExtensions: [
    'js',
    'jsx',
    'ts',
    'tsx',
    'json',
    'node'
  ],
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules'],
  modulePaths: ['<rootDir>src'],
  testMatch: ['<rootDir>src/**/*(*.)@(spec|test).[tj]s?(x)'],
  rootDir: '../../',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>config/jest/setupTest.ts']
}
```

Comment: I added declare module '*.module.css' and declare module '*.module.scss', but it does't work

Comment: So. I tried to add this in my jest.config:                                                                                     
modulePaths: [
        '<rootDir>src',
    ],